# Program does not execute properly when double clicked. "A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again."

Tags: java

I am trying to get a simple guessing game to run when I click the desktop icon. The game prompts the user for inputs in the command window. The program does not have a real user interface aside from one dialogue box. I understand that opening jar files using "javaw.exe" does not open command prompt programs, so I added a dialogue box just to have some indication that it was being opened.

The name of the jar is "guessme.jar"

I have gotten the jar to run properly from the command window by navigating to the proper directory and then issuing the following command :
`java -jar guessme.jar`

I would expect double clicking the icon would open my dialogue box. 
However, when I try to open the jar using a double click, I get the following error:

> A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again.

Then I get another dialogue box which says:

> A Java Exception has occurred.

I am using JDK 13.0.1. 
I made sure that the bin is at the top of the class path. I checked that the system was compiling with the correct version of Java. 
Issuing `java -version` yields 13.0.1.
Issuing `javac -version` also yields 13.0.1.

I wrote the program in Eclipse. I archived the file using the command prompt. 
My package name does not include java or any such keywords. Its just my email.

I have looked around and did not find anyone else who had the same issue. Thank you.

Comment: Please include the code you have written.

Comment: Did you maybe use the Standard Widget Toolkit for your dialog box? Because those libraries are not in the standard Java library / path.